# ExtJS - How do I pass ID when syncing store?

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, store

On ExtJS 6.2, I'm getting data from database like this: `myStore.load({id: myId);`.

How do I pass the ID while syncing?
This doesn't work: `myStore.sync({id: myId);`

I'm using a REST proxy and my URL is in this format: `mydomain/users/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by extending `Ext.data.proxy.Rest` and overriding the `buildUrl` method to be able to extract the ID from the request parameters. Then I used this overridden proxy in my model:

```js
Ext.define('MYPROJ.proxy.Settings', {
   extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
   alias  : 'proxy.settings',
   buildUrl(request) {
      const url = this.callParent([request]);
      const id  = request.getParams().id;

      if (id) {
         delete request.getParams().id;

         const proxyUrl = request.getProxy().getUrl();

         return url.replace(proxyUrl, `${proxyUrl}/${id}`);
      }

      return url;
   }
});

Ext.define('MYPROJ.model.Setting', {
   extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
   alias   : 'model.setting',

   clientIdProperty: 'clientId',

   fields: [{
      name    : 'id',
      type    : 'int',
      persist : false
   }, {
      name   : 'name',
      type   : 'string',
      unique : true
   }],

   proxy: {
      type : 'settings', // <- Use overridden proxy here
      url  : `/something/settings`
   }
});
```

Then in my code I can use `sync()` like this:

```js
const myID = 10;

this.settingsStore.load({id: myID});

//...

this.settingsStore.sync({params: {id: myID}});
```

When `sync()` is called `myID` will be extracted from params on `MYPROJ.proxy.Settings` and added to the URL (/something/settings/10).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `myStore.sync()`, you don't need to specify `id`. The `sync` function will examine the store contents, and add/delete/update records as needed.

When using REST, you can set `writeRecordId` of `Ext.data.write.Writer` (see [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.writer.Writer.html#cfg-writeRecordId)) to `false`, since with REST `id` is usually appended to the URL, as in your case.

Comment: But I have a very specific case where I need to pass the ID, the ID is not available in the models stored in the store. All store models use the same ID. The database was not well designed that's why. I solved it in a hacky way, passing the ID on the params object, then on the buildUrl function I get the ID, add it to the URL and remove it from the params. I'm looking for a better way to solve it.